# Unable to use Cognito password with spaces, also unclear error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

When using a password that contains spaces I get the following error from cognito:

```
1 validation error detected: Value at 'password' failed 
to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular 
expression pattern: [\S]+
```

If it's not possible to have spaces in the password, is it possible to change the resulting error text? I fear the unclear error message might negatively affect sign ups.

Answer (score 0):

The best place for this suggestion might be to register it on the AWS forums.

In your code you might want to manually rewrite the messages from Cognito one-by-one. AWS Cognito error messages do not excel at clarity and are hardly documented.